# Why does a C++ string not appear to have been initialized correctly when seen through the output of "print" in GDB?

Tags: string, gdb, flush

I have the following piece of code.

```
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

std::string lowerCase(const std::string &exprName)
{
    std::string dummy(exprName);
    char firstChar = tolower(exprName.at(0));
    dummy.replace(0, 1, &firstChar);
    return dummy;
}
```

When I step through the code using GDB, and break at line 6 (std::string dummy(exprName)), I expect dummy to be empty. But when I print it using

```
p dummy
```

GDB prints a value for the variable in the following way

```
Breakpoint 1, lowerCase (exprName=...) at Utility.cpp:49
49      std::string dummy("");

(gdb) print dummy
$1 = {
  static npos = 18446744073709551615, 
  _M_dataplus = {
    <std::allocator<char>> = {
      <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
    members of std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider: 
    _M_p = 0x634261 "Expr * input2 = facade->derefE(facade->varE(v));\nNode * subject = f->"
  }
}
```

Also, if I step to the next line of code, i.e.

```
char firstChar = tolower(exprName.at(0));
```

and I print the value of "dummy" in GDB, it's value remains the same and doesn't change to the value of exprName. I printed "exprName" and it definitely contains a different value!

This is baffling! Why would dummy not be initialized to the same value as that of exprName?

Comment: It 'contains data' in just the same way as an un-erased white-board holds whatever was written on it during it's last use.

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly what *uninitialized* means: the value is (sort of) unpredictable, and when you look at the contents, it is likely to not make sense.

In your case the `_M_ptr` pointer accidentally happens to point into a valid memory range, so you do see something which looks like a string. The contents depend on values temporarily stored on the stack by another function, called before this one.

Comment: I understand that. But within the function, even if I call dummy.clear() after declaring dummy and then assign the value of "exprName", on the second line, which is "char firstChar = tolower(exprName.at(0));", if I try to print the value of dummy in GDB it still shows the same output and it's baffling me!

Comment: the `clear()` method expects the object to be in an consistant state, which it isn't.  There are no guarantees that the object will be more consistent after calling `clear()`.  The only method which does have this guarantee, is the constructor.